# why is socketio client not connecting to nextjs custom server?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, socket.io

this is my first time working with websockets. i have a custom nextjs server, here is the code:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const user = require("./server/api/userAPI");
const game = require("./server/api/gameAPI");

// Vanilla API routes
const app = next({ dev, hostname, PORT });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const expressApp = express();
    const httpServer = createServer(expressApp);
    const io = new Server(httpServer);

    expressApp.use(express.json());
    expressApp.use("/user", user);
    expressApp.use("/game", game);

    expressApp.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });


    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("socket connected");
      const count = io.engine.clientsCount;
      console.log(count);
    });

    expressApp.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });

  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

and here is the client in app.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const socket = io();

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log(socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
  });


  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Page>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Page>
        </ChakraProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

i am expecting, on both the server side and the client side, for the console to log the connection message. however neither is logging.

edit:

am getting the following error in browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path for both ends in order for them to meet.

Client:

```
const socket = io({path: "/api/socketio"});
```

Server:

```
const io = new Server(httpServer, {path: "/api/socketio"});
```